# C - How we could write/read/delete a Btree on file?

Tags: c, file, b-tree

I 'm newbie on C

I have a insert, delete, search code for BTree that works perfect.
But I want to run code in file. I searched a lot but couldn't find a right answer.

Could you  explain with an example how can I do this?

This is a part of my C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "bTree.h"

#define MAX_KEYS (1024)

void main(){
    bTree test = btCreate();
    btInsert(test, 55);
}

struct btNode
{
    int isLeaf;     /* is this a leaf node? */
    int numKeys;    /* how many keys does this node contain? */
    int keys[MAX_KEYS];
    struct btNode *kids[MAX_KEYS + 1];  /* kids[i] holds nodes < keys[i] */
};

bTree btCreate()
{
    bTree b;

    b = malloc(sizeof(b));
    assert(b);

    b->isLeaf = 1;
    b->numKeys = 0;

    return b;
}

void btDestroy(bTree b)
{
    int i;

    if (!b->isLeaf) {
        for (i = 0; i < b->numKeys + 1; i++) {
            btDestroy(b->kids[i]);
        }
    }

    free(b);
}

/* return smallest index i in sorted array such that key <= a[i] */
/* (or n if there is no such index) */
static int
searchKey(int n, const int *a, int key)
{
    int lo;
    int hi;
    int mid;

    /* invariant: a[lo] < key <= a[hi] */
    lo = -1;
    hi = n;

    while (lo + 1 < hi) {
        mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        if (a[mid] == key) {
            return mid;
        }
        else if (a[mid] < key) {
            lo = mid;
        }
        else {
            hi = mid;
        }
    }

    return hi;
}

int btSearch(bTree b, int key)
{
    int pos;

    /* have to check for empty tree */
    if (b->numKeys == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    /* look for smallest position that key fits below */
    pos = searchKey(b->numKeys, b->keys, key);

    if (pos < b->numKeys && b->keys[pos] == key) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return(!b->isLeaf && btSearch(b->kids[pos], key));
    }
}

/* insert a new key into a tree */
/* returns new right sibling if the node splits */
/* and puts the median in *median */
/* else returns 0 */
static bTree btInsertInternal(bTree b, int key, int *median)
{
    int pos;
    int mid;
    bTree b2;

    pos = searchKey(b->numKeys, b->keys, key);

    if (pos < b->numKeys && b->keys[pos] == key) {
        /* nothing to do */
        return 0;
    }

    if (b->isLeaf) {

        /* everybody above pos moves up one space */
        memmove(&b->keys[pos + 1], &b->keys[pos], sizeof(*(b->keys)) * (b->numKeys - pos));
        b->keys[pos] = key;
        b->numKeys++;

    }
    else {

        /* insert in child */
        b2 = btInsertInternal(b->kids[pos], key, &mid);

        /* maybe insert a new key in b */
        if (b2) {

            /* every key above pos moves up one space */
            memmove(&b->keys[pos + 1], &b->keys[pos], sizeof(*(b->keys)) * (b->numKeys - pos));
            /* new kid goes in pos + 1*/
            memmove(&b->kids[pos + 2], &b->kids[pos + 1], sizeof(*(b->keys)) * (b->numKeys - pos));

            b->keys[pos] = mid;
            b->kids[pos + 1] = b2;
            b->numKeys++;
        }
    }

    /* we waste a tiny bit of space by splitting now
    * instead of on next insert */
    if (b->numKeys >= MAX_KEYS) {
        mid = b->numKeys / 2;

        *median = b->keys[mid];

        /* make a new node for keys > median */
        /* picture is:
        *
        *      3 5 7
        *      A B C D
        *
        * becomes
        *          (5)
        *      3        7
        *      A B      C D
        */
        b2 = malloc(sizeof(*b2));

        b2->numKeys = b->numKeys - mid - 1;
        b2->isLeaf = b->isLeaf;

        memmove(b2->keys, &b->keys[mid + 1], sizeof(*(b->keys)) * b2->numKeys);
        if (!b->isLeaf) {
            memmove(b2->kids, &b->kids[mid + 1], sizeof(*(b->kids)) * (b2->numKeys + 1));
        }

        b->numKeys = mid;

        return b2;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void btInsert(bTree b, int key)
{
    bTree b1;   /* new left child */
    bTree b2;   /* new right child */
    int median;

    b2 = btInsertInternal(b, key, &median);

    if (b2) {
        /* basic issue here is that we are at the root */
        /* so if we split, we have to make a new root */

        b1 = malloc(sizeof(*b1));
        assert(b1);

        /* copy root to b1 */
        memmove(b1, b, sizeof(*b));

        /* make root point to b1 and b2 */
        b->numKeys = 1;
        b->isLeaf = 0;
        b->keys[0] = median;
        b->kids[0] = b1;
        b->kids[1] = b2;
    }
}
```

**bTree.h:**

```
/* implementation of a B-tree */
typedef struct btNode *bTree;

/* create a new empty tree */
bTree btCreate(void);

/* free a tree */
void btDestroy(bTree t);

/* return nonzero if key is present in tree */
int btSearch(bTree t, int key);

/* insert a new element into a tree */
void btInsert(bTree t, int key);

/* print all keys of the tree in order */
void btPrintKeys(bTree t);
```

thanks

Comment: I don't follow. What do you mean by execute code in a file?

Comment: BTree is designed to be stored in files but you need to change your code a bit. Replace pointers to children in btNode with file offsets. Instead of pointer dereference, you seek the file with a given offset and read or write a record. You also need some kind of in-file memory management so that you can allocate or free a record in a file (it is simple because all records are of the same size).